# Count returns wrong result

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a user model and currently there is only one row. I am trying to count number of rows of whole User table,  here is my code:

```
var count int64
db.Model(&models.User{}).Count(count)
fmt.Println(count)
```

I am expecting **1** but it is  printing **0**.
What is the correct way to print number of row in table using **gorm**?

update: My user model:

```
package models

import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Password string
    Admin bool
}
```

Comment: We can't tell what `db.Model`, `models.User`, and `Count` are or what they do. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `count` variable to `Counter` as a reference, as it is now it is passed by value. You should do:

```
db.Model(&models.User{}).Count(&count)
```

Comment: its still printing 0

Comment: enable [logging](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/advanced.html#logger) to see the generated query, then try it against your database.